# Probability of drawing two or more black balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability of drawing with replacement two or more black balls from a hat with 12 balls: four black, four red, and four blue? We are drawing 4 balls from a hat. I have drawn tree diagram. For example, if the first ball drawn is the red one, then we have possible sequences:

Red, Red, Black, Black   (probability is $\frac{1}{3^{4}}$ )

Red, Blue, Black, Black

Red,  Black, Black (probability is $\frac{1}{3^3}$ )

Red,  Black, Blue,  Black

Red,  Black, Red,  Black

so probability for the case when the first ball is red is
$4 \frac{1}{3^{4}}  +  \frac{1}{3^{3}} $

In similar way, I found the probabilities for cases when the first ball is the blue one or black one.

I found that the result is 0.4074. Can someone just check if this is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The number of draws isn't specify in your question. Do you draw a ball exactly four times? In that case you could use binomial distribution.

Comment: It is going to be *much* easier on you if you treat blue and red balls as the same category, "*not black*".  This will reduce the case work considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many draws do you make? From your example I guess 4 but it is not specified in the question.

This could be interpreted as an binomial distribution $X \sim Bin(n=4, p = 1/3)$ so what you should calculate is $P(X \geq 2) = 1- P(X \leq 1) = 1- (P(X = 1) + P(X = 0)) \approx 0.4075$.

Comment: I have edited the question, 4 balls are drawn.

Comment: $n=12$?  No.  $n$ would be the number of draws being made, which you just said in the line before you are assuming is $4$.

Comment: My bad, corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can ease your casework two ways.  First, consider the blue and red balls to be nonblack with probability $\frac 23$.  You don't need to distinguish them.  Second, all different orders of a given combination have the same probability, so compute the chance of one and multiply by the number of different orders.

You can get two black and two nonblack with chance ${4 \choose 2}\left( \frac 13\right)^2\left( \frac 23\right)^2=\frac {24}{81}$
You can get three black and one nonblack with chance ${4 \choose 3}\left( \frac 13\right)^3\left( \frac 23\right)^1=\frac {8}{81}$
You can get four black and no nonblack with chance ${4 \choose 4}\left( \frac 13\right)^4\left( \frac 23\right)^0=\frac {1}{81}$

For a total of $\frac {33}{81}.\ \ $  $0.4074$ is approximately correct.  I would leave it as a fraction unless you are asked for a decimal.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:  Thanks.  Fixed.